# what is the name of this book by Rudin?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

[Product and sum of positive operators is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583921/product-and-sum-of-positive-operators-is-positive)

in this question OP states that :

> There is a theorem in Rudin (12.32) that says that for every $T\in B(H)$ we have an equivalence:
>   $T$ is positive $\Leftrightarrow$ $T$ is self adjoint, i.e.$T=T^*$ and $\sigma(T)\subset [0,\infty)$.

I checked "principles of mathematical analysis" and it has got just 11 sections so I guess it's not the book which OP was referring to.

I'd like to know which is it and if possible other books where this same theorem is proven.

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That book is *Functional Analysis*, published by McGraw-Hill.